# how to identify curl command for URL is down or performance issue

Tags: performance, curl, jenkins-pipeline

we have a pipeline job which goes over all the Jenkins servers and check its status using the commands:

```
curl  --connect-timeout 10 "$JENKINS_URL" >/dev/null
status=`echo $?`
 if [ "$status" == "7" ];
```

my question is it possible to identify responses from curl command for performance issues (for example, FS is full and it takes some time for Jenkins to respond) or URL issue (Jenkins is down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 timeout settings you can play with:

- `--connect-timeout <s>` is the timeout for establishing an HTTP connection
- `--max-time <s>` is the timeout for receiving a reply

For example `--connect-timeout 10 --max-time 20`.

But if the server isn't accepting a connection in time, there would be no way to distinguish that from a down server, other than to increase the `connect-timeout` value in order to wait longer.